# VirtualBox WordPress redirects to port 80

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, virtualbox, portforwarding

I'm running on OSX 10.9.2. I just set up LAMP on Lubuntu in VirtualBox so that I could run a development server through VirtualBox. I changed my `/etc/apache2/ports.conf` to listen on 8080 instead of 80, and I set up my VirtualBox port forwarding with NAT with the following configuration:

```
+--------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
| Name   | Protocol | Host IP | Host Port | Guest IP | Guest Port |
+--------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
| Apache | TCP      |         | 8080      |          | 8080       |
+--------+----------+---------+-----------+----------+------------+
```

I can access websites that I have created in `/var/www/` such as `/var/www/testwebsite/` by accessing `localhost:8080/testwebsite` on my host machine (the Mac). I'm trying to install a WordPress site on my guest machine. I have followed [Digital Ocean's How To Install WordPress on Ubuntu 12.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-12-04) and so far it works when I access `http://localhost:8080/wordpresssite` inside the guest machine (Lubuntu), but when I try to access `http://localhost:8080/wordpresssite` on my host machine, it redirects to  `http://localhost/wordpresssite`, when then can't be found. How do I fix this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up following this guide: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

In my `wp-config.php`, I added the following two lines

```
define('WP_HOME', '<host ip address here>:8080/wordpresssite');
define('WP_SITEURL','<host ip address here>:8080/wordpresssite');
```

It's a little hacky, but it works for my own testing purposes. Also, apparently I've been running into an issue where `localhost:8080/wordpresssite` redirects to `localhost/wordpresssite` on Chrome. I think that this might be a caching issue, since it doesn't redirect when I'm in incognito.

Comment: Just for anyone that is lurking. This will work. But the other answer is better. WP looks at the wp-options table for the URL. Then it looks at the wp-config.php file, and if those two defines are found, it overrides the wp-options table value. In most cases, using the wp-options table is best. The only time I would use the wp-config.php if it was for a local/dev system, and the wp-config.php file is NOT copied to the live system, but the database might be.

Answer (score 0):

Access your database and click in the options table.

Change Url to something like : http://10.165.12.167:8080/wp/

Where `8080` is your Apache port.

Clear your browser's cache and try again.